# website uses an invalid security certificate

Tags: apache, .htaccess, security, ssl

I have website on `ubuntu` with `apache` server. Domain is from `godaddy`. When I type `example.com` it's running file under SSL (with https). But, for `www.example.com` it's giving me below error.

> www.example.com uses an invalid security certificate. The certificate is only valid for the following names: someother.com, www.someother.com, someother.com (Error code: ssl_error_bad_cert_domain)

**What I did?**

I tried to talk with `godaddy`. They suggested me to disable SSL v3 from apache server. Everything is ok from their side.

Then I changed `ssl.conf` file with this: `SSLProtocol All -SSLv2 -SSLv3` according to [this](https://www.linode.com/docs/security/security-patches/disabling-sslv3-for-poodle) documentation. But, still it's giving me the same error.

**configurations**

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
   ServerAdmin myemail@gmail.com
   ServerName example.com
   ServerAlias www.example.com
   DocumentRoot /var/www/example/public_html
   ErrorLog /var/www/example/error.log
   CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
<VirtualHost _default_:443>
    ServerName example.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/example/public_html
    ErrorLog /var/www/example/error.log
    SSLEngine on
    SSLCertificateFile /etc/apache2/ssl/example.crt
    SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/apache2/ssl/example.key
    SSLCertificateChainFile /etc/apache2/ssl/example-bundle.crt
</VirtualHost>
```

Let me know if you need more info.

Comment: Well, adapt the configuration for www.example.com for HTTPS? Apparently HTTPS is only configured for example.com, so the settings and certificate for this (default) domain are used.

Comment: @sebix: While generating CSR I used `www.example.com` as a domain name. How come it's possible to use other website's certificate?

Comment: Please show the output of `openssl x509 -text -noout -in [path to cert]` to clarify which cert do you have.

Comment: @sebix: I did it. It says common name (`CN: www.example.com`) . `X509v3 Subject Alternative Name: DNS:www.example.com, DNS:example.com`..  do you want any other info from that response?

Comment: Then the configuration is wrong. Please show all configuration related to HTTPS.

Comment: might be better on serverfault?  but are you sure www.example and example both point to the same IP / Same apache instance?

Comment: @Doon: Is there any way to check that? coz according to configurations, it's coming in to same IP address.

Comment: I solved this problem by adding `ServerAlias www.example.com` in VirtualHost settings. Thanks for your efforts guys.